# Probing that $\sin^2{\phi}+\cos^2{\phi}=1$ for cross and dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem statement:

*Use the cross product to find the sine angle $\phi$ between the vectors $\vec{u}=2i+j-k$ and $\vec{v}=-3i-2j+4k$. Then use the dot product to find the cosine angle $\phi$ for the same vectors. Finally show that $\sin^2{\phi}+\cos^2{\phi}=1$ for the values calculated.*

**My solution**:

*First part -sine angle-*:

$\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=2i-5j-k$

$\|\vec{u}\times\vec{v}\|=\sqrt{30}$

$\|\vec{u}\|=\sqrt{6}$

$\|\vec{v}\|=\sqrt{29}$

Therefore:

$\sin{\phi}=\sqrt{\frac{30}{174}}$

*Second part -cosine angle-*:

$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=-12$

Then:

$\cos{\phi}=-\frac{12}{\sqrt{174}}$

**BUT** when I do

$\sin^2{\phi}+\cos^2{\phi}\neq 1$

What I did wrong?

Comment: What are $i,j,k$?

Comment: The physics representation for vectors.

Comment: I didn't follow the whole calcutation, but what's wrong with $30/174+144/174=1$?

Comment: You did it correctly, and $\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi=1$.

Comment: Sorry, a calculation problem.

Comment: I want to ask why that relation is true ($\sin^2{\phi}+\cos^2{\phi}=1$)?

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdonez are you asking about the Pythagorean identity?

Comment: No, I'm asking why is that for dot and cross product?

Comment: You always have $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ that's Pythagorean identity, it's independent from how you get to the equation...

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez: I think the identity you are looking for is Lagrange's identity.

Answer (score 0):

As it is pointed out in the comments above, the calculations don't fail the Pythagorean identity, since
$$\sin^2{\phi}+\cos^2{\phi} = \frac{30}{174} + \frac{144}{174} = 1.$$